# Regex expression to exclude both prefix and suffix

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to build an expression which will match all text **EXCLUDING** text with prefix `'abc'` **AND** suffix `'def'` (text which only has the prefix **OR** the suffix is ok).

I've tried the following:
`^(?!([a][b][c]])).*(?!([d][e][f])$)`, but it doesn't match text which only has one of the criterias (i.e. abc.xxx fails, as well as xxx.pdf, though they should pass)

I understand the answer is related to 'look behind' but i'm still not quite sure how to achieve this behavior

I've also tried the following:
`^(?<!([a][b][c])).*(?!([d][e][f])$)`, but again, with no luck

Comment: Which dialect are you using?

Comment: `^(?!abc.*def$).*`

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks... turn out I was over complicating things!

Comment: @SebastianProske This expression doesn't seem to work: http://regexr.com/3dvco

Comment: @strah I don't see the problem, it matches as the suffix is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple and combine it into a single lookahead to check both conditions:

```
^(?!abc.*def$).*
```

Answer (score 3):

`^((abc.*\.(?!def))|((?!abc).*\.def))$`

I think there can be a simpler solution, but this one will work as you wanted it.

`[a][b][c]` can be simplified to `abc`, the same goes for `def`.
The first part of the pattern matches `abc.*\.` without `def` at the end.
The second part matches `.*\.def` without the prefix `abc`.

Here is a visual representation of the pattern:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kBCevl6FPqlC3oVV)